# Conditional Regex: if A and B, choose B

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to extract IDs from a string of the following format: `Name ID`, where the two are separated by white space.

*Example*:

```
'Riverside 456'
```

Sometimes, the ID is followed by the letter `A` or `B` (separated by white space):

```
'Riverside 456 A'
```

In this case I want to extract '456 A' instead of just '456':
I tried to accomplish this with the following regex:

```
(\d{1,3}) | (\d{1,3}\s[AB])
```

The conditional operator `|` does not quite work in this setting as I only get numerical IDs. Any suggestions how to properly set up regex in this setting?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is that the whole line, if so can you do a substring?

Comment: Can't you do a zero or one check (?)  it seems the white space would be 0 or 1 also

Comment: try `'(\d{1,3}[\ AB]*)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just reversing the order of the statements to have the more specific one first. I.e.:

```
     (\d{1,3}\s[AB]) | (\d{1,3})
```

Comment: Alternation like this always loses in performance to optional groups.

Comment: As I said: this solution is not optimal in terms of regex performance due to backtracking that will have to work hard checking 1 to 3 digits in both branches. This is a readable solution for beginners, but this is definitely bad practice in production.

Answer (score 2):

Your `(\d{1,3})|(\d{1,3}\s[AB])` will always match the first branch as in an NFA regex, if the alternation group is not anchored on either side, the first branch that matches "wins", and the rest of the branches to the right are not tested against.

You can use an optional group:

```
\d{1,3}(?:\s[AB])?
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yV4lC9/1)

Add a [`$` at the end](https://regex101.com/r/yV4lC9/2) if the value you need is always at the end of the string.

If there can be more than 1 whitespace, add `+` after `\s`. Or `*` if there can be zero o more whitespaces.

Note that the last `?` quantifier is greedy, so if there is a whitespace and `A` or `B`, they will be part of the match.

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/ym8JDV):

```
import re
rx = r'\d{1,3}(?:\s[AB])?'
s = ['Riverside 456 A', 'Riverside 456']
print([re.search(rx, x).group() for x in s])
```

Comment: @chizze Please check the answer and please let know if it works for you or not, and if anything needs more clarification.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Very thorough and explanatory. I implemented it and it works nicely. Didn't know that the optional group will be included if found, so this is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an optional part that you might want to include, but not necessarily need, you could just use an "at most one time" quantifier:

```
Riverside (\d{1,3}(?: [AB])?)
```

The `?:` marks groups as "not-capturing", so they won't be returned. And the `?` tells it to either match it once or ignore it.

Comment: I think it needs to be capturing, from the question **In this case I want to extract '456 A'**

Comment: Actually, I believe `Riverside` cannot be hardcoded, OP needs to extract the ID from an arbitrary string.

Comment: Well...without more information this is as much a valid assumption as mine is. ;) The regular expression without any kind of prefix can match all kinds of things besides what OP actually wants to have. And after all, it is just one possible solution. And replacing `Riverside` with `\w+` is pretty straight-forward from here.

Comment: @PyNEwbie If you look closely, you will notice that it IS capturing, because the first group includes the non-capturing group. I pretty much just made sure that the resulting matches are similar to what OP currently has to avoid confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\s?[AB]?)$')
print(pattern.search('Riverside 456').group(0))    # => '456'
print(pattern.search('Riverside 456 A').group(0))  # => '456 A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use alternation

```
p = re.compile('''(\d{1,3}\s[AB]|\d{1,3})$''')
```

NB `$` or maybe `\s` at the end (outside the group) is important, otherwise it will capture both `123 C` and `1234` as `123` rather than fail to match.